# Date pipe issue

Tags: angular, ionic3

does angular date pipe get the date from local machine?

Anyhow I want to get a tomorrow's date, i've used this `moment.utc().startOf('day').add(1, "days").toISOString()` but it fails when i changed machine's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular like any other client side framework runs on client machine (translated into JavaScript code). And whether you get date through plain **JavaScript** GetDate method or **momentjs** library it will read client machine's date and time.

If you are doubtful about the accuracy of client machine's Date and time then provide it through server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe does not get date from anywhere as `Date` is pipe's input. Pipe itself only formats it.